# iOS 14.4.2 / Big Sur 11.2.3 connect to mac localhost from iPhone

Tags: ios, localhost, macos-big-sur

I have a rails server running on localhost:3000, and want to connect to it from my iPhone, which is on the same wifi network.  I found my mac's IP address 192.XXX.X.XX and when i go to http://192.XXX.X.XX:3000 from my iphone, all I get is "Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server".  I checked and I don't hae any firewall on my mac.  Does anyone know how I might resolve this, or even troubleshoot it myself?